# Is using NodeJS in Android app (HTML5 JavaScript PhoneGap) a good decision?

Tags: android, html, node.js, cordova

I want to build a WebSocket based chat application. I am trying to develop this application for **Smart Phones** with the help of HTML5, JavaScript, Websockets, like GTalk and using PhoneGap for binding it for Smart Phones. Is it a good idea to make it with NodeJS? WHat will be pros and cons of using Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. 
Please check this:
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/get-chatty-with-nodejs-and-html5